Why do the (Ok & Cancel) buttons not appear on my ServiceNow UI Action GlideModal popup?
I’m new to JavaScript and programming, but I want to create a ServiceNow UI Action for a function called ‘Request Info.’ The popup shows up correctly, but the Ok & Cancel buttons are missing. Can anyone help me with this issue?
The code I am using:
function checkawaitingtype() {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        updateticket();
    } else {
        var myModal = new GlideModal('awaiting_info_modal', false);
        myModal.setTitle('Provide Awaiting Info Details');
        // Fetch options for the dropdown from the u_awaiting_info_reason field
        var awaitingReasonOptions = getAwaitingReasonOptions(); // Implement this function
        var modalBody = '<div>' +
            '<label for="awaiting_reason">Awaiting Info Reason</label>' +
            '<select id="awaiting_reason" style="width: 100%;">' +
            '<option value="">Select Awaiting Info Reason</option>';
        // Populate dropdown options dynamically
        awaitingReasonOptions.forEach(function (option) {
            modalBody += '<option value="' + option.value + '">' + option.label + '</option>';
        });
        modalBody += '</select>' +
            '<label for="comments" style="margin-top: 10px;">Additional Comments</label>' +
            '<textarea id="comments" rows="4" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>' +
            '</div>';
        myModal.setBody(modalBody, false, false);
        
        myModal.addDecoration({
            text: 'OK',
            color: 'primary',
            id: 'ok_button'
        });
        myModal.addDecoration({
            text: 'Cancel',
            color: 'secondary',
            id: 'cancel_button'
        });
        var okFunction = function () {
            var awaiting_reason = document.getElementById('awaiting_reason').value;
            var comments = document.getElementById('comments').value;
            if (awaiting_reason === '') {
                alert('Please select an awaiting info reason');
            } else if (comments === '') {
                alert('Please specify details in comments');
            } else {
                // Populate the Awaiting Info Reason field
                g_form.setValue('u_awaiting_info_reason', awaiting_reason);
                g_form.setValue('comments', comments);
                g_form.setDisplay('u_awaiting_info_reason', true);
                g_form.setMandatory('u_awaiting_info_reason', true);
                g_form.setMandatory('comments', true);
                gsftSubmit(null, g_form.getFormElement(), 'requestMoreInformation');
                myModal.destroy();
            }
        };
        var cancelFunction = function () {
            myModal.destroy();
        };
        document.getElementById('ok_button').onclick = okFunction;
        document.getElementById('cancel_button').onclick = cancelFunction;
        myModal.render();
    }
}
function updateticket() {
    new global.StateFlow().processFlow(current, '9a028a63c3123100d6d210c422d3ae11', 'manual');
    action.setRedirectURL(current);
}
// Implement this function to fetch options from the u_awaiting_info_reason field
function getAwaitingReasonOptions() {
    // Replace with your logic to retrieve options (e.g., from a REST API or predefined list)
    return [
        { value: '1', label: 'Awaiting Contact' },
        { value: '2', label: 'Awaiting Change' },
        { value: '3', label: 'Awaiting Problem' },
        { value: '4', label: 'Awaiting Vendor' }
        // Add more options as needed
    ];
}


I got some help from ChatGPT to improve the code but it did not resolve the issue.
How the pop up look like without the buttonscription here
Error 1 from the browser developer mode (F12)
Error 2 from the browser developer mode (F12)here
For Reproducible Example, I am not expert so I do not know if it can be tested in any Javascript environment or not, but I know if you have a ServiceNow instance (A dev one should be sufficient), you can go and create a new UI action and use the above code then you will get the pop-up without the buttons.

document.getElementById('ok_button') is undefined - probably because you try to add those listeners BEFORE you render the modal

Your GlideModal uses a UI page of awaiting_info_modal but you haven't told us what that is... Why not put this logic inside of your UI page / processing script instead?

Also addDecoration isn't a GlideModal method that does anything

I'd suggest creating a UI page, and using <g:dialog_buttons_ok_cancel/>, then doing the update logic in your processing script.
